# Python regex to validate expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to check the validity of some expressions using a Python regex. 
Expressions could be like these ones:

```
(expand(function_1(<<TAG_1>>)) or expand(function_2(<<TAG_2>>))) 
                                                            and tag_value(<<TAG_3>>) >= 3
```

What I need to validate is that all expression is valid (means that it has a correct number of parenthesis, all arithmetical operators are present and so on) and especially, that inside *expand* function there is only one argument; 
means that the following example is wrong:

```
(expand(function_1(<<TAG_1>>) and function_3(<<TAG_4>>)) or 
                              expand(function_2(<<TAG_2>>))) and tag_value(<<TAG_3>>) >= 3
```

To do that, I wrote this Python regex:

```
expand\s*\(\s*(\<\<(.+)\>\>\s*[\+-/\*\<\>\=\s*0-9]+|([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*\(\s*(\<\<(.+)\>\>|\<\<(.+)\>\>\s*,\s*.*)\))\s*\)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/s5OYO4WmMB_l5ExU)

As you can see from the debuggex demo, the string used as test is not valid

```
(expand( function_1(<<TAG_1>>) and <<pippo>> < 3) or 
           expand(function_2(<<TAG_2>>))) and tag_value(<<TAG_3>>) >= 3
```

More in details, seems that it takes from the first *expand* until the last one.

How is it possible fix the regex to achieve this goal?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't check if parenthesis are balanced with the re module. You need the [pypi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) or to build a parser by hand.

Comment: For parsing tasks like this, I like http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

Comment: So is it not possible check the expand content in this expressions by regex? I thought that could be a problem of greedy/lazy regex...

Comment: Even if you could do it with a regex (which it seems you can't), it's likely to be head-exploding and so for everyone's sanity using or writing a 'proper' parser is probably preferable.

Comment: Not possible with the re module. Possible with the regex module. However using a parsing module as suggested is more appropriate.